# What's wrong with this Magento install

Tags: php, magento

When I installed the Magento program on my local environment, after finishing the install, I accessed the URL `http://localhost/job/magento/`  and it shows the following error.

```
There has been an error processing your request
Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Trace:
#0 D:\www\job\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(712): Zend_Uri::factory('{{base_url}}')
#1 D:\www\job\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(313): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 D:\www\job\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 D:\www\job\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 D:\www\job\magento\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 D:\www\job\magento\index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {ma
```

How to correct it? Thank you!

Comment: some of magneto localhost [installation troubleshoot](http://www.sankaranand.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-troubleshoot-problems-while-installing-magento-in-localhost/)

Comment: I received this error when installing with Chrome, but FireFox worked fine (ver. 1.11.2.0).

Answer (score 5):

Please install magento with localhost Ip Address 127.0.0.1

Ex: http://127.0.0.1/job/magento/

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /job on this server. the webserver shows why?

Answer (score 3):

Try loading https://localhost/magento.

Note the **https** instead of http.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem by checking the third checkbox ("Skip Base URL validation before next step") in the first screen after the agreement.

I installed under a FQD on a LAMP server.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem changing the directory permission to 755, as it's said on installation guide
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_installation_guide

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by checking the third checkbox ("Skip Base URL validation before next step") in the first screen after the agreement.

and using firefox

when i use chrome , i meet issue after installing.

i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will definitely helps you... https://127.0.0.1/magento/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change base_url variable directly from the database.

Use phpmyadmin or any other software to go to your magento database.

In "core_config_data" table find entry for web/unsecure/base_url and change it to either "{{base_url}}" or http://127.0.0.1
Do the same for web/secure/base_url

Comment: i am sorry, there is no web/unsecure/base_url  entry in In "core_config_data" table

Comment: the field is config_id,scope,scope_id,path,value. there is no record  r web/unsecure/base_url

Comment: Something is wrong with your install. Try do it again. But as suggested by others, go to 127.0.0.1/job/magento/

Comment: when i access using 127.0.0.1/job/magento/  the error shows the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem on Wamp and XAMPP., nearly give up.
Finally find the solution, Magento 1.6 can not work properly with WAMP 2.1 and XMAPP 1.7, I guess it caused by Mysql version, not sure. 
but after I change WAMP to 2.0 i, everything is fine. Magento 1.6 is running well.
Download WAMP2.0i : http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.0/WampServer2.0i.exe/download

I failed to install on Chrome, but success on firefox.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me when I install magento sample data after installing magneto, you should do it other way around (same data wipes out core_config_data table).

from http://www.magentocommerce.com/download:

sample data - Must be installed prior to the basic Magento Installation.

Answer (score 0):

When you install 'configure' step of magento installation, you MUST use 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/' at base url textbox, instead of 'http://localhost/magento' do this.

Good Luck.

Comment: Will you explain why you MUST use IP instead of localhost ? It's usually already set in hosts.

Answer (score 0):

There has been an error processing your request `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user \\\’demo\\\’@\\\’localhost\\\’ (using password: YES)`

This error will occur if there is no database connection .. First you need to check your `local.xml` file ... then check the url path in `core_config_data` in your database .... clear your `cache session` and `locks` ....  if the error still appear after doing all these things \\"YOU JUST LOOK IN YOUR `app/etc` folder ...... if there is any extra `xml` file just delete that particular file ...... i got the same issue .. found a `local_org.xml` file in `etc` folder ....... JUST DELETE THAT FILE IT WILL WORK PROPERLY ..........  grin